Res2Net50 with AM-Softmax for Speaker Verification: Why does the average_accuracy return only 0 or 100?
I'm building a Res2Net50 model for a speaker verification task. I'm using AM-Softmax as the loss function with the following parameters:
Margin: 0.2
Scale: 10
After training the model for 5 epochs on a dataset with 1,000 data points (each containing the speaker ID and corresponding WAV file processed into MFCC features), the performance seems odd. Specifically, the average_accuracy metric always returns only 0% or 100%, which doesn't make sense.
Here’s my setup:
(Actually this setting was after several data-frame and csv file manipulation - i would include my note book for you guy to learn more)
Dataset: 1,000 datapoints consisting of speaker IDs and a file WAV files. Each WAV file is transformed into MFCCs as input to the model.
Model: Res2Net50. (with embedding dimension = 512_
Loss Function: AM-Softmax with a margin of 0.2 and scale of 10.
I've tried to solve the issue with AM-Softmax (e.g., improper scaling or margin values - initially I would use scale = 30, then lower it down but it didn't work) and tried experimenting with minor tweaks, but the issue persists. The metrics don't seem to improve, and the precision is either perfect or completely off.
What I have tried:
Verified that the MFCC preprocessing is consistent and produces reasonable features.
Checked that the speaker IDs are correctly encoded.
Experimented with learning rates and optimizer settings, but the average_accuracy behavior doesn’t change.
So my Question is:
What might be causing this unusual behavior in the average_accuracy metric, and how can I debug or resolve it?
Any insights into AM-Softmax tuning, data preparation, or evaluation metrics would be greatly appreciated!
Google Colab Notebook
Here’s the notebook for reference:
Res2Net50 Speaker Verification Model.
My AM-Softmax Code Block:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

class AMSoftmax(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_dim, num_classes, margin=0.2, scale=30, **kwargs):
        super(AMSoftmax, self).__init__()

        self.m = margin
        self.s = scale
        self.in_feats = embedding_dim
        self.W = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.randn(embedding_dim, num_classes), requires_grad=True)
        self.ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        nn.init.xavier_normal_(self.W, gain=1)

        print('Initialised AM-Softmax m=%.3f s=%.3f'%(self.m, self.s))

    def forward(self, x, label=None):
        assert len(x.shape) == 3
        label = label.repeat_interleave(x.shape[1])  # Repeat labels across the sequence length dimension
        x = x.reshape(-1, self.in_feats)

        assert x.size()[0] == label.size()[0]
        assert x.size()[1] == self.in_feats
        
        device = x.device
        x_norm = torch.norm(x, p=2, dim=1, keepdim=True).clamp(min=1e-12)
        x_norm = torch.div(x, x_norm)
        
        w_norm = torch.norm(self.W, p=2, dim=0, keepdim=True).clamp(min=1e-12)
        w_norm = torch.div(self.W, w_norm)
        
        # Ensure both x_norm and w_norm are on the same device
        w_norm = w_norm.to(device)  # Move w_norm to the same device as x_norm if they are not on the same device
        
        # Perform matrix multiplication
        costh = torch.mm(x_norm, w_norm) # Cosine similarity between x_norm and w_norm
        
        
        label_view = label.view(-1, 1)
    
        
        if label_view.is_cuda: 
            label_view = label_view.cpu()
            
        # Scatter to modify costh
        delt_costh = torch.zeros(costh.size()).scatter_(1, label_view, self.m) # Add margin

        
        if x.is_cuda: 
            delt_costh = delt_costh.cuda()
            
        costh_m = costh - delt_costh # Apply the margin
        costh_m_s = self.s * costh_m # Scale by s
        
        loss    = self.ce(costh_m_s, label) # Cross-entropy loss
        # Accuracy
        prec1   = accuracy(costh_m_s.detach(), label.detach(), topk=(1,))[0]
    
        return loss, prec1
        
    def accuracy(output, target, topk=(1,)):
        """Computes the precision@k for the specified values of k"""
        maxk = max(topk)
        batch_size = target.size(0)
    
        _, pred = output.topk(maxk, 1, True, True)
        pred = pred.t()
        correct = pred.eq(target.view(1, -1).expand_as(pred))
    
        res = []
        for k in topk:
            correct_k = correct[:k].view(-1).float().sum(0, keepdim=True)
            res.append(correct_k.mul_(100.0 / batch_size))
        return res

